# Пунктуация в СПП. Использование "будь то"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, ссп

1) **Стоило ему нелестно выразиться об однокласснике, тут же это распространилось среди всего класса.**
"Стоило ему нелестно выразиться об однокласснике" — это придаточное времени?

2) Объясните, пожалуйста, что это за конструкция — **будь то**?
Она тоже относится к придаточным? Если да, то к какому виду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А. **Это  нестандартное сложноподчиненное предложение с условно-временным придаточным, двойной союз СТОИЛО...КАК**

**Стоило** ему нелестно выразиться об однокласснике, (как) тут же это распространилось среди всего класса.

Б. **БУДЬ ТО ― союз**

Употр. при присоединении к обобщающему слову ряда однородных членов предложения, раскрывающих или конкретизирующих обобщающее слово; союз имеет значение, сходное со значениями слов ***например, как то*.**

**Знаки препинания могут быть разными, они выбираются для каждого случая по общим правилам, а также могут быть авторскими:**

Пираньи нападают на всё живое, что им встретится на пути: **будь то рыба или оказавшееся в воде животное.** [Пираньи // «Мурзилка», 1999]

Реставратору необходимо хорошо знать породы древесины, их свойства, уметь определять породу по внешнему виду ― **будь то старая древесина или новая.**

Дело в том, что у всех таких деятелей, **будь то самозванцы, Стенька Разин, декабристы или большевики,** есть две общие черты. [Вера Краснова, Павел Кузенков. Романовы: империя верных // «Эксперт», 2014

При проектировании и строительстве любых транспортных путей, **будь то нефтепровод или автодорога,** должны быть предусмотрены специальные переходы для северных оленей. [Секрет заполярного агропрома // «Эксперт», 2014]

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!